# Angular Router navigate and reload need to render the component once but renders twice

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am having a special condition where i need to redirect to a url and reload.

I am using this method from router:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
this.reload();
```

Where `this.reload()` is the function that is working outside the angular zone to force reload the page. I need to force reload as i don't have control with some assets coming from server.

The code of reload is:

```
public reload(): any {
    return this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        location.reload()
    });
}
```

**The issue is:**

I am navigated to the login in the beginning and then the page is reloaded which is the default behavior.

**Required output:**

just navigate without rendering the component and reload like when we hit some unauthorized url we are redirected to the login page in most of the sites.

Comment: You might skip the `navigateByUrl` and instead replace the window's `location` property: `location.replace('myUrl');`

Comment: It only reloads more and neither change the url of the routes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is interested in doing the things as i am doing, I have solved the issue by first going to the url and then reloading the page.

First import `Location`:

```
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
```

Then use `go()` to navigate to the certain url you are expecting.

```
this.location.go('login');
```

then use the reload method to reload the browser.

```
this.reload();
```

where the reload function is:

```
public reload(): any {
    return this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        location.reload()
    });
}
```

**Note:**

This method is only suitable if you want to navigate and reload without showing the page load to the user twice.